# Count total when grouping by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a table with the following information:

```
--------------------------------------
| client_name | supplier | completed |
--------------------------------------
| Acme_1      | Sup_1    | 0         |
| Acme_1      | Sup_1    | 0         |
| Acme_1      | Sup_1    | 1         |
| Acme_1      | Sup_2    | 0         |
| Acme_1      | Sup_1    | 1         |
| Acme_1      | Sup_1    | 0         |
| Acme_2      | Sup_1    | 0         |
| Acme_2      | Sup_1    | 0         |
| Acme_2      | Sup_3    | 0         |
| Acme_1      | Sup_1    | 1         |
| Acme_3      | Sup_2    | 0         |
| Acme_2      | Sup_3    | 0         |
--------------------------------------
```

What I need to have is a result that shows how many times `Sup_x` supplied to `Acme_x`. So for the above table I need an overview thar looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------
| supplier | client_name | total     |
--------------------------------------
| Sup_1    | Acme_1      | 6         |
| Sup_1    | Acme_2      | 2         |
| Sup_2    | Acme_1      | 1         |
| Sup_2    | Acme_3      | 1         |
| Sup_3    | Acme_2      | 2         |
--------------------------------------
```

But I'm completely lost. I'm trying to do `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`'s . But I'm not even getting close to what I need. For example:

```
SELECT 
      [supplier]
      ,[client_name]
      ,COUNT([client_name]) AS total
  FROM data
  GROUP BY 
      [client_name]
      --,[supplier]
```

But this query doesn't really give what I need.

What query do I need to get the desired resukt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [supplier], [client_name], COUNT(1) AS total
FROM data
GROUP BY [supplier], [client_name];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have, and like I said, this is not giving me the desired results.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot soemthing in my real query that made me believe something was wrong. But the query works fine. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you change `COUNT([client_name])` to `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT 
[supplier]
,[client_name]
,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM data
GROUP BY 
[client_name],[supplier]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be the following:

SELECT 
      [supplier]
      ,[client_name]
      ,COUNT([completed]) AS total
  FROM data
  GROUP BY [client_name],[supplier]

Explanation:

- The "Group By" clause will return only distinct row sets for the selected columns in the select          statement. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)
- The count will just count the number of rows for the specified [supplier],[client_name] set.

Please do not hesitate to contact me should you need more help or clarification

Comment: Where does `completed` come from in `COUNT([completed])`?

Comment: I thought it was part of the table. Check: --------------------------------------
| client_name | supplier | completed |
--------------------------------------

Comment: Check the post at the very begining

Comment: Ahh my bad.  Didn't see that.